# Where to find existing API?

Tags: api

I have been given the name of one API which already exists in Dev Sandbox. However I'm unable to find the same. I checked APIs in the environment and it only displays the option to generate WSDL. I checked installed packages but I'm not able to find the given api. I also checked packages and none exist there as well. 
I have no clue if they are using Rest or Soap.

Please suggest where can I find this api.

FYI- Im using Enterprise edition.

Comment: Check if there is any Resource URLMapping given so you can search by that name.

Comment: No Resource URL Mapping mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it is a custom API you will most likely find it in your apex classes.

You will need to look at the apex classes if the name is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But there are tonnes of classes. Is there any specific method to find the exact class?

Comment: Since you know the name of the API you can do a search across your code. The easiest way to do this is by connecting your IDE (e.g. Eclipse, IntelliJ/illuminated cloud, sublime/mavens mate) to your org.  If it is a rest API you can also search for @RestResource which annotates a class as an API

Comment: Thanks... I found it through Eclipse.... Thanks again...